# Searching for an optimal data storage type PYTHON

Tags: python, list, sorting, object

i have following problem i am solving that reguires me to store lots of parameters and i would for general purposes consider it a calendar application. I am solving the problem in **PYTHON** since its the only limited ability i have. I am learning the language, im by far NOT an expert or a skilled user of it yet.

I have a class that is a mainstay of my calendar.

```
class DayOfLife(object): 

def __init__(self, date, index, stary, mlady, muze_slouzit_mladeho = [], muze_slouzit_stareho = []):

        self.date = date
        self.index = index
        self.muze_slouzit_mladeho = muze_slouzit_mladeho
        self.muze_slouzit_stareho = muze_slouzit_stareho
        self.stary = stary
        self.mlady = mlady
```

**muze_slouzit_mladeho** and **_stareho** is a list of possible people who can be used for work.

**Index** is parameter describing how "bothersome" a day can be. Mondays are better then Sundays and saturdays etc.

**stary** and **mlady** is a definitive choice of a selected persons for current day. (those i expect my program to generate)

I create a **list** of days (DayOfLife object) and assign each a date in "2017-01-01" format.

I then populate the list of days to have all the values i need except stary and mlady (those i expect my program to generate)

**NOW the ISSUE**.
I am not sure if my approach is the "good" one if i want to perform stuff like :

**1:** sort the list by total amount of available people for each day (number of **keys** in **muze_slouzit_mladeho**, since i would love to populate those hardest days first. At the same time i need to access easily and quickly the day before and day after of those days.

So something like sort the list by number of keys in those list attributes (**muze_slouzit_mladeho**)and then assign something from the possible keys and either remove or mark as used somehow the same keys in day **before** and **after** since on key can not be in two following days. (Persons cannot attend two days in a row). At the moment i feel that if i sort the list i would have to then iterate through the entire list to find the previous day by date and update its key values. It feels better to be able to just write something like

```
day[i-1] remove key
day[i+1] remove key
```

I am unsure how would i do that at all. I have no idea how to use databases at the moment. I think my data type will have to evolve into something else, i might need to add another list to keep scores of people who i removed due to the "two days in a row rule" instead of removing it in the original.

I think i will think of something but i expect it to be terribly inefficient. So i would like to hear some opinion on how to approach that. Do i have to learn SQLite? Will it help? Can i somehow make the array of DayOfLife objects indexable? Or can i access the objects by their attributes? I am not sure if that would work. I might really be dumb here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `dict` with the date as key and values with your `DayOfLife object` and `amount of available people`, e.g

```
my_dict = {'Date':2017-01-01, 'DayOfLife':<DayOfLife object>, 'amount':10}
```

Sort `my_diict` using `key = my_dict['amount']` to a `list object`.

Access Day before/after:

```
 E.g. current object Date = 2017-01-01
 Day before = 2017-01-01 - 1 = 2016-12-31; my_dict[ 2016-12-31]
 Day after= 2017-01-01 + 1 = 2017-01-02; my_dict[ 2017-01-02]
```

You sure be want to save your Data permanently, so you have to decide How to?
For now start with useing `csv module`.